# why is my second main method (bubble sorting?) not running?

Tags: java, arrays, bubble-sort

the first part of my code is working fine, but the bubble sort part is not running at all, at least I don't believe it is, as I cannot get my code to print the sorted list. I have tried making everything doubles, and adding in to return the list, but I still cannot make it work

This is my code thus far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        //create array
        double[] list = new double[10];       
        //Generates 10 Random Numbers in the range 1 -20
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
          list[i] = (int)(Math.random()* 100 + 1);
        }//end for loop
        System.out.println("The unsorted list is: " + Arrays.toString(list));     

        //find max number
        double max = -1;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i] > max) max = list[i];
        }
        System.out.println("The largest value is " + max);
        
    }
    
    
    public static double[] bubbleSort(double[] list) 
        {
          double temp;
             
        for (int i = list.length - 1; i > 0; i--) 
            {
               for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
               {
                 if (list[j] > list[j + 1]) 
                 {
                 temp = list[j];
                 list[j] = list[j + 1];
                 list[j + 1] = temp;  
                 System.out.println("The sorted list is: " + bubbleSort(list) + " ");
                 
                 }
                 
               }
            }
        return list;
                

}
}
```

Comment: I apologize for the formatting issues, this is my first time posting a question

Comment: i ended up calling bubble sort as the answer i got suggested, in the println asking for the sorted list, and it still isnt running

Comment: as for it not being a conventional bubble sort, I'm not sure, as my professor gave us this specific code to work with, minus my addition of trying to make it print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java (and most languages), only the "Main" method runs automatically; that is the entry point for your code. Other methods won't run unless you call them.

You should look up "Control flow" to generally understand more of what gets run and when, but for now, you just need to call that method. Calling a method is what you're doing with code like `Arrays.toString(list)`, but in this case the method is in the local namespace, so you just need `bubbleSort(list)`

Comment: I called the method in the println for the sorted list, and I'm still not sure what the issue is, but I will look more into control flow such as you suggested

Comment: Edit your code to show the new version and I'll take a look

Comment: I put just the relevant section this time as the rest is running correctly

Comment: So now you're calling `bubbleSort` at every step of your other sort method, which is almost certainly wrong - move that call up to the top level of the main function. That said it looks like it should be running repeatedly as is; my first guess for why it isn't is that you're passing an already-sorted list, so that whole `if` block isn't running.

Comment: moving it into the main method is now printing, but a string of numbers, letters, and symbols, but it is printing now

Comment: That sounds like a memory address to me. Probably you're printing something java doesn't have built in support for printing. (Relative to a lot of newer languages, Java won't implicitly format a lot of things to be printed in a readable way.)